# using javascript to change text on a window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the problem at the moment is that when the windows get resized some text gets cut off. I've seen websites where when the window resizes the text changes to an abbreviation or another word. People were telling me that this is angular js but since then I've tried finding something related to it and couldn't. So i'm back to using good old javascript and here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/duy8zvmm/71/

The problem is that i don't want this first

```
var myspan = document.getElementById('players-signedup');

if (myspan.innerText) {
  myspan.innerText = "Players";
}
else
  if (myspan.textContent) {
    myspan.textContent = "Players";
}
```

and can't understand why i need it there, because the resize if statements i have do work, i have tested using background colors on a div. So i can't understand why they aren't working here

Comment: Is the example supposed to be a feature detection?

Comment: Hi Teemu. The example is supposed to do the following. On window load figure out the size of the window, depending on the width put in place either P: or Players text. Then if the window resizes, change the text based on the width being greater or less than 1260 or what ever i specified.. it works for changing background color. Just not working for changing text for some reason?

Comment: If `myspan` is empty, any of the `if`s can't pass. Use `in` operator (it finds a property from prototype chain too) to detect if a property exists in an object.

Comment: sorry Teemu i'm not a javascript wiz and i'm struggling. Never used the in operator before can you help me with example code?

Comment: [No need to be a wiz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), `if ('innenrText' in myspan) {...}` should do the trick.